# unclear error from dart2js checked mode

Tags: dart, dart2js

My original error was `An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`. After dart2js runs with the default settings it's pretty difficult to read and I was having trouble debugging the output, so I added these options to my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
- $dart2js:
    checked: true
    sourceMaps: true
    verbose: true
    minify: false
```

I was expecting something to break, but I was hoping the error message would be clear enough that I could work it out, but I understand the error I'm getting.

The new error I'm getting is:

```
Error: 
  dart<.wrapException()
  dart<._rootHandleUncaughtError_closure.call$0()
  dart<._microtaskLoop()
  dart<._startMicrotaskLoop<()
  dart<._AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate_internalCallback.call$1<()
  dart<.invokeClosure_closure0.call$0()
  dart<._IsolateContext.eval$1()
  dart<._callInIsolate()
  dart<.invokeClosure<()
  dart<.convertDartClosureToJS/$function</<()
```

It looks like dart is having some trouble converting a closure to a js function. I'd have thought this would be done when `dart2js` is run and not while the application is running in the browser.

My code doesn't have any explicit closures, but I do use `async await`. Am I right in assuming that those would be converted into closures?

Just in case it's relevant, I'm also using Angular2.

## Update

It appears that my problems are being caused by my use of the `HttpRequest.request()` from `dart:html`.

```
HttpRequest res = await HttpRequest.request( "${API_URL}/login",
  method      : "POST",
  responseType: "json",
  mimeType    : "application/json",
  sendData    : JSON.encode( req_data ) );

print( res.status );
```

If I remove checked mode and build this is giving me the `An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable` error.

Comment: You could try `pub build --mode=debug` to disable tree-shaking and minification. How does the script tag look like that you use to add the dart script to `index.html`? Might be some timing issue.

Comment: I'll give `--mode=debug` a go and let you know what I get.

I'm using these script tags:
`<script async src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>`
`<script async src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>`

Comment: Can you publish the project (reduce by all that is not absolutely necessary to reproduce) to a GitHub repository?

Comment: As far as I can see it's just that `HttpRequest.request()` function that is causing the issue. I'm going to change it to `new HttpRequest()..open(...)` and see if that helps. If not I'll try and put a github repo together.

Comment: If it's only this call, you could try if you can reproduce the error in http://dartpad.dartlang.org

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in dartpad because I can't make an http request.

Comment: Why not? I think it should work.

Comment: I put a simple test json file on in server's public folder, but I can't seem to request it from within dartpad. I tested it with curl and it works fine. I'm going to answer the question because I've changed the way I'm doing the requests and it seems to be working now.

Comment: It might be a CORS issue. You could try https://cors-test.appspot.com/test which responds with a short JSON snippet. If you solved it and are not interested to further investigate, it's fine of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have fixed the problem by changing my use of the `HttpRequest` class.

From:

```
HttpRequest res = await HttpRequest.request( "${API_URL}/login",
  method      : "POST",
  responseType: "json",
  mimeType    : "application/json",
  sendData    : JSON.encode( req_data ) );

print( res.status );
```

To:

```
HttpRequest res = new HttpRequest()
  ..open( "POST", "${API_URL}/login" );

req
  ..onLoadEnd.listen( ( ProgressEvent e ) {
      print( res.status );
    })
  ..send( JSON.encode( req_data ) );
```

I'm not sure what the actual problem was, but this way I don't get either the `InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable` or the longer dart error:

```
Error: 
  dart<.wrapException()
  dart<._rootHandleUncaughtError_closure.call$0()
  dart<._microtaskLoop()
  dart<._startMicrotaskLoop<()
  dart<._AsyncRun__initializeScheduleImmediate_internalCallback.call$1<()
  dart<.invokeClosure_closure0.call$0()
  dart<._IsolateContext.eval$1()
  dart<._callInIsolate()
  dart<.invokeClosure<()
  dart<.convertDartClosureToJS/$function</<()
```

My guess is that `dart2js` is hving some trouble with `async await` "implicit" closures and is much happier when I use an "explicit here's a function that closes over it's environment" closure.

Thanks to Günter Zöchbauer for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The API is better, more intuitive.
For example your request :

```
var client = new BrowserClient();

var response = await client.post("${API_URL}/login", 
                                 body: JSON.encode( req_data ));
var data = JSON.decode(response.body);
client.close();
```

And you could probably see in the parameters if you want more precision in the way you want to define your request.

Comment: You could edit your existing answer instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thanks. This one is working now, but I'll keep that in mind for the next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use http package instead

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/http

Comment: Why? What does it do that dart's built in one doesn't?